# definition for tabs in vimrc doesn't work as expected

Tags: vim

I recently added a the following lines to my vimrc:

```
set noexpandtab
set copyindent
set preserveindent
set softtabstop=8
set shiftwidth=8
set tabstop=8
```

from what I read it was supposed to make tabs be understood as tabs (and not be replaced by spaces) and make them all 8 spaces long. However, my tabs are still 4 spaces long and they're being replaced by actual spaces, although backspacing does delete all 4 spaces.

The interesting part is that when I input them manually after the file is open everything works as expected. What am I missing here?

Probably doesn't matter but my vim version is 7.4.

Comment: In general, if a Vim setting is not staying how you set it, use `:verbose` to figure out what is overriding your setting. For example, `:verbose set expandtab?` should tell you what file last modified the expandtab option. I'd guess you have a filetype plugin or autocmd interfering.

Comment: Great, it worked. It was being modified by `/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/python.vim`. I hadn't noticed before but only the `.py` were presenting that behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Ben 's comment, I tried the command `:verbose set expandtab?` and apparently the definitions of `vimrc` were being overwritten in this case by the file `/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/python.vim`. So just commenting the indenting option lines in that file did the trick.